# OpenOffice writer - programmatically updating tables with cell formulas

Tags: java, openoffice-writer, uno

I'm really stuck trying to find out how to force a programmatic refresh of openoffice writer (3.3) cell calculations when the cell values are bookmarks and the bookmarks are updated programmatically (via UNO calls in Java).

Example

```
| start | stop  | duration    |
| 9:30  | 11:30 | = <A2>-<B2> | <= cell formula
```

This works fine when the user is manually editing the table, the value is updated when they move to the next cell. However if I update the values programmatically by inserting text into bookmarks in the cells the calculated cells do not update. They will update if you click in the table but I would like this to be automatic.

Bookmark are in the table like this.

```
| start     | stop    | duration    |
| <start0>  | <stop0> | = <A2>-<B2> |
```

Example code to update the  bookmark:

```
XBookmarksSupplier xBookmarksSupplier = (XBookmarksSupplier) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XBookmarksSupplier.class, document); 
XNameAccess xNamedBookmarks = xBookmarksSupplier.getBookmarks(); 

Object bookmark = xNamedBookmarks.getByName("stop0"); 
XTextContent xBookmarkContent = (XTextContent) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextContent.class, bookmark); 
xBookmarkContent.getAnchor().setString("11:30"); 

// code needed to force calculation of duration cell
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured it out myself. The key is to use [XRefreshable](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/util/XRefreshable.html) and know that cell formulas in tables count as "text fields" - so using the traditional long-winded (but fun) UNO meta-programming style...

- query text fields supplier from XTextDocument instance
- query refreshable instance from text fields enumeration
- call refresh

Update: This will not work if the source cells in the formula being updated have a format applied to them, the format of the destination cell does not matter.

Code

```
XTextFieldsSupplier tfSupplier = (XTextFieldsSupplier) 
        UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextFieldsSupplier.class, document); 
XRefreshable refreshable = (XRefreshable) 
        UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XRefreshable.class, tfSupplier.getTextFields()); 
refreshable.refresh();
```